# Error in function does not pass test

Tags: mongodb

I'm learning about MongoDb and the exercise of the module is about a function in MongoDb to return the match in the database with the parameter "Director" that I pass but doesn't pass the test. This is my code:

In movies.js

```
      exports.byDirector = function(db, director, callback) {
  // TODO: implement

  db.collection('movies').find(
    {"director" : director}).sort({title : 1}).toArray(function(error, docs){
    if (error){
      console.log(error);
      process.exit(1);
    }
    docs.forEach(function(doc){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
    });
    process.exit(0);
  })
  callback(null, []);
};
```

This is the function's test:

```
  it('returns multiple results ordered by title', function(done) {
    dbInterface.byDirector(db, 'George Lucas', function(error, docs) {
      assert.ifError(error);
      assert.ok(Array.isArray(docs));
      assert.equal(docs.length, 4);
      assert.equal(docs[0].title, 'Attack of the Clones');
      assert.equal(docs[1].title, 'Revenge of the Sith');
      assert.equal(docs[2].title, 'Star Wars');
      assert.equal(docs[3].title, 'The Phantom Menace');
      docs.forEach(function(doc) {
        delete doc._id;
      });
      assert.deepEqual(Object.keys(docs[0]), ['title', 'year', 'director']);
      ++succeeded;
      georgeLucasMovies = docs;
      done();
    });
  });
  var succeeded = 3;
```

What's wrong?
Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `callback` function outside the `toArray` callback function

Try this

```
    exports.byDirector = function(db, director, callback) {
  // TODO: implement

  db.collection('movies').find(
    {"director" : director}).sort({title : 1}).toArray(function(error, docs){
    if (error){
      callback(err, null);
    }
    docs.forEach(function(doc){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
    });
    callback(null, docs);
  });
};
```